# In-line TryGetValue in If conditon and evaluate it's Value

Tags: c#, dictionary

Is there any way how to write TryGetValue on one line in If condition. Normal way of calling TryGetValue would be:

```
string value;
Dictionary.TryGetValue("Key", out value);
If(value == "condition") { ... }
```

What I am looking for would be something like this.

```
If(Dictionary.TryGetValue("Key", out string) == "Condition") { ... }
```

I know that line wouldn't work, however it shows what is desired result.

Is there any way how to achieve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use the returned `bool` first but then you can use the `out` parameter(with >= C# 7):

```
if (Dictionary.TryGetValue("Key", out string value) && value == "Condition")
{
    //...
}
```

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier):

> Starting with C# 7.0, you can declare the out variable in the argument
>   list of the method call, rather than in a separate variable
>   declaration.

If you're not using C#7 or you want it even shorter you could use this extension:

```
public static bool TryEvaluateValue<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TKey key, Func<TValue, bool> evalValue)
{
    TValue val;
    if(!dict.TryGetValue(key, out val))
        return false;
    return evalValue(val);
}
```

Then your `if`-condition becomes:

```
if (Dictionary.TryEvaluateValue("Key", value => value == "Condition"))
{
    //...
}
```