# How to resolve key not found exception in dictionary collection

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to store details present in a dictionary into SQL Server using ado.net connection, but I get a key not found exception when I try to insert values into the database.

```
if(option==2)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Database=Demo;Integrated Security=SSPI");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tnlFourWheeler(Vno, years, cost,color,fuel,doors,seats) " +
            " VALUES (@Vno, @years, @cost,@color,@fuel,@doors,@seats)", con);
        for (int i = 0; i < keyValuePairs.Count; i++)
        {
            FourWheeler t = (FourWheeler)keyValuePairs[i];
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vno", t.vehicleNumber);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@years", t.numberOfYears);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cost", t.cost);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@color", t.color);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fuel", t.fuelType);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doors", t.doors);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@seats", t.seats);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        con.Close();
```

Comment: keyValuePairs is my dictionary reference

Comment: `FourWheeler)keyValuePairs[i]` will return the value of the specified key, not index. You could just use a `foreach` over the `keyValuePairs.Values` collection.

Comment: Unrelated tips: SqlConnection and SqlCommand are both IDisposable so each should be in a `using` block. Once you've done that, you don't need to Close the connection because it will be closed by the implicit Dispose as it exits the block. Note that the second time round the for loop you will be trying to add a parameter with the same name as already added to the same list of parameters: move the `cmd` within the loop might be an idea.

Comment: Not clear what is type for FourWheeler looks like a list you are adding into . You can always use  KeyValuePair.ContainsKey[i] or you can all use TryGetValue or make a extension method that you can call. Refer this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52362941/in-line-trygetvalue-in-if-conditon-and-evaluate-its-value

Comment: Also...Consider using a transaction, to prevent the scenario where half the values have been inserted and then something goes wrong, leaving only those values in the database rather than a complete set. And you may want to read [can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: You need to.tell us what type `keyValuePairs` is, because you are using an indexer on it, but your words make it sound like it is a Dictionary. If it It a dictionary, then the code you are using is trying to lookup an entry where the Key is a numerical value, which probably isn't what you want, and would lead to the Key not found error described in the question.

Comment: Better idea: Use a Table-Valued Parameter to do a single bulk insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` is not indexed by array-index, it's indexed by key.

Do this instead (replace `TKey` with your actual `TKey`):

```
foreach( KeyValuePair<TKey,FourWheeler> kvp in keyValuePairs )
{
    FourWheeler t = kvp.Value;

    // ...
}
```

Or:

```
foreach( TKey key in keyValuePairs.Keys )
{
    FourWheeler t = keyValuePairs[key];

    // ...
}
```